# How to maintain user data state when user is not logged in and the client machine crashes?

Tags: java, web-applications, state, shopping-cart

There is a web application for shopping chart, user can pick products say p1 from page 1, p3 from page 3 and p7 from page 7.

He can then move ahead and will be presented with total amount and the payment transaction will take place. But suppose user has selected some products and suddenly his computer crashes, he again logs in to find out that he's product selection is vanished. How would you manage to handle such situation ?

Comment: Ever heard of cookies? `localStorage`?

Comment: I Know cookies, but the question arise when cookies are disabled on client machine.

Comment: Also try making a webapp that doesn't crash so much to need a use-case for the recovery :)

Comment: Well, you're storing user accounts somewhere, right? ...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The above test case is for Guest User.

Answer (score 1):

You could either go for cookes or for HTML 5 local storage. I suggest the latter.

Have a look here for detailed information: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html